# Laravel 5 - Multiple Custom Service Provider

Tags: php, laravel-5, service-provider

I've created a service provider called `\App\Providers\HelperServiceProvider.php` with this content:

```
<?php namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Session;
use View;

class HelperServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        foreach (glob(app_path().'/Helpers/*.php') as $filename){
            require_once($filename);
        }
    }

}
```

And also included in `providers` in `\config\app.php`

This works fine until recently I wanted to add a new provider for different purposes. So I created a new one `App\Providers\ComposerServiceProvider.php`

```
<?php namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Session;
use View;

class ComposerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        # This content doesn't really matter. It still doesn't work even if I remove it.
        # View composer for partials.alert
        # Some code
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
    }

}
```

And included in the config too so it looks like this:

```
<?php   
        /* ^Some other things
         *
         * Application Service Providers...
         */
        'App\Providers\AppServiceProvider',
        'App\Providers\BusServiceProvider',
        'App\Providers\ConfigServiceProvider',
        'App\Providers\EventServiceProvider',
        'App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider',
        'App\Providers\HelperServiceProvider',
        'App\Providers\ComposerServiceProvider',
```

But it came out as Internal Server Error. It works fine when I take out from the providers config. I've tried everything I can think of. I tried removing everything inside boot(), changing the order of the providers, renaming the providers, but none of them worked. I can't get to the php/apache log file for other technical reason. Is there any problem with this implementation that I missed?

Comment: Without an error message it's hard to say what the problem is... Please check the latest log file in `storage/logs`.

Comment: @lukasgeiter I've looked through the laravel log files the messages there have nothing related to this.

Comment: And it doesn't even work with just the empty `ComposerServiceProvider` included?

Comment: @lukasgeiter exactly. That's why it's very weird. I don't know if it's a bug or not. It's just the fact that I added 2 custom providers that triggers this error. Doesn't matter of the name or its implementation. Other providers by other 3rd party packages below that works fine.

Comment: I'm sorry but without the error I can't help you. Is it impossible that you get to the apache log?